# How to pass a parameter in a button and get value in the code behind to redirect to another page based on the value of parameter in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, parameters, commandparameter

I am thinking if the windows phone 7 button event is similar to ASP.NET development with C#, something like in the button, I set value to commandparameter in the XAML, and in the code behind, I get the commandparameter and redirect the page.

I haven't found any good examples for button event handling, any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to do something like <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Title}" Click="Button_Click" /> and I want to get the Title from the Button_Click event handler at code behind.

Answer (score 12):

For the xaml:

```xml
<Button Tag="pageAddress" Click="Button_Click" />
```

And then on the code-behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button _button = (Button)sender;
     NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(_button.Tag.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What difference between using Tag property and CommandParameter property? I guess I can do Tag="{Binding Title}" same as CommandParameter="{Binding Title}" ?

Comment: Hi Teemu, would you be able to give me a short example how can I pass Item object which has Icon, LineOne, LineTwo and LineThree properties to another page using Tag within Button control, please? I found the Tag property in Button control is really useful when passing an object. Thank you very much

Comment: I normally use MVVM and with that the Tag property is perfect for referring items. I can't really fit the whole Tag example into this comment.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend you use a command parameter as you mentioned. So in your xaml do something like this:

```xml
<Button x:name="myButton" CommandParameter="{Binding Title}" Click="myButton_Click"/>
```

And in your C# code something like this:

```cs
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button _myButton = (Button)sender;
    string value = _myButton.CommandParameter.ToString();
}
```

Really it's pretty similar to Teemu's answer although I must admit I haven't used the *Tag*
element before. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on MSDN, the Tag element should work pretty nicely as it can store *custom* information that you can access in your code behind (or viewmodel).